# update result of function in class javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a class like this:

```
class test{
 _var;
 set var (value) {
    this._var = value
  }

  getFunc(val){
   return this._var*val
  }
}
```

I want when update _var all used getFuc results be update

I Want that rendered function result be updated

```
var test=new test()
test.var=3
test.getFunc(2) //return 6
test.var=4
//now the getFunc must be return 8
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, your code works...

Comment: I dont understand what's your question. code is already working

Comment: What do you mean by "*all used getFunc results*"? Are you referring to the previously returned value that has already been logged, do you want that to get updated?

Comment: Yes bergi I Want that rendered function result be updated

Comment: `test.var = 4;  test.getFunc(2) ` returning 8. Its working correctly

Comment: @smko That's not possible, it has already happened. You need to call `getFunc` again after changing the `var`, and overwrite the old result - but there is no way for `test` to know where it should store such results automatically. In addition, the `console` log cannot be altered at all.

Comment: @smko Hello, I wrote an answer regarding your problem consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Small programme. How it can change the value by calling that function based on the user Input Hope this will resolve your problem.

```js
class test{
 _var;
 set var(value) {
    this._var = value
  }
  
 get var(){
  return this._var
 }

  getFunc(val){
   return this._var*val
  }
}

var tested = new test();

let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let EnterNumber = document.getElementById("number");

function countMe(){
  if(EnterNumber){
  tested.var = EnterNumber.value;
  }
        console.log(tested.var)
        var result = tested.getFunc(2);
        
     
      counter.innerHTML = Number(result);
}

EnterNumber.addEventListener("keyup", countMe);
```

```html
<input id='number' type='number' value='EnterNumber'/>

<div id='counter'></div>
```